# How to display subcategory articles in the category view? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

I have the wordpress category widget installed on my website that lists all categories/subcategories on my site and their hierachy:

```
Watch Accessories (1)
- Straps (1)
Watch Glossary (5)
Watch Guides (1)
- Maintenance (1)
Watch News (2)
- New Releases (2)
Watch Reviews (7)
- Christopher Ward (1)
- Hamilton (1)
- Seiko (2)
- Tissot (2)
- Vostok (1)
```

I am using the following permalink structure:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

When I click on the parent categories (Example: http://www.domain.com/watch-reviews/) it shows the category view and lists all articles in that category.

But when I click on a subcategory (example: http://www.domain.com/watch-reviews/seiko/) it doesn't show the category view, it doesn't list all the articles in the subcategory. Instead it redirects to the first article in the sub category.

How can I get Wordpress to display all articles in a subcategory?

Feel free to visit domain.com to experience this issue for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is for ex these category structure

Watch Accessories (2)

- Straps (1)

You have 2 article

Article 1 (Watch Accessories) Select one category

Article 2 (Watch Accessories, Straps)  Select 2 category , I mean select parent also.

This will display all the article with sub category for Accessories category.

Answer (score 0):

Your subcategory is available at http://www.zapby.com/seiko/.

Comment: Why does the category widget not link to this url?

Comment: By default, WordPress should make nested sub-categories appear as nested directories in the URI. I'm guessing something is messed up in rewriting on account of that you are not using a category base. Try setting a category base under Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: Did setting a category base fix this problem?